# como representar um campo monetário com pontos e vírgula em javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou com uma enorme dúvida.

Preciso pegar os valores que estão no banco de dados com casas decimais de 3 (por exemplo: 56826.497) e mostrar na tela o valor 56.826,497. Já tentei usar o **maskMoney** e o **priceformat**, mas não deram certo.

O **maskMoney** até serve pra **inserir** os valores corretamente, me obrigando a inserir somente números e da forma que eu formatar (56.826,497). Porém, na hora que ele carrega o valor do banco de dados pra visualizar na tela, aparece como 56826.497.
detalhe: estou carregando os valores assim:

No HTML eu estou usando o código abaixo:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------- no cabeçalho
* <script src="../scripts/js/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
//------------------------------------------------------------------ no cabeçalho
* <script>
$(function(){
   $('#commod_com_imp, #serv_com_imp, #commod_sem_imp, #serv_sem_imp').maskMoney({ thousands: '.', decimal: ',' });
            });
//------------------------------------------------------------------ no momento de carregar a página

function preenche_primeira_vez() { // Preenchimento na primeira vez  
    indice_bd=0;
    get_num_registros();
    $("input").prop('disabled',true); // Colocando todos os campos como desabilitado
    $("select").prop('disabled',true); // Colocando todos os campos como desabilitado
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../funcoes.php",
        data:{acao:"consulta_preco", offset:indice_bd, numlinhas:1, nome_tabela:'cliente,preco'},
            success:function(resp_consulta) {
                consulta_formatada = $.parseJSON(resp_consulta);
                $("input[name=commodity_com_imp]").val(consulta_formatada[0].commodity_com_imp.replace("." , ","));

//------------------------------------------------------------------ no body
<div class="texto_e_valor_com_3">
<div class="texto">Preço commodity com imposto (R$/m<sup>3</sup>)</div>
<div class="valor"><input type="text" MAXLENGTH="10" name="commodity_com_imp" id="commod_com_imp"/></div>
```

Comment: muito obrigado. ajudou bastante

Comment: Possivel duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11018/como-representar-dinheiro-em-javascript

Answer (score 5):

O JavaScript possui problemas de arredondamento, portanto qualquer solução que inclua a função `.toFixed` não é uma boa opção. Eu recomendo a utilização de bibliotecas já testadas.

**Eu** gosto de utilizar duas bibliotecas em conjunto, que me dão flexibilidade total para resolver esse tipo de problema; Para cálculos eu uso o [bigmoney.js](https://github.com/demchenkoe/bigmoney.js) e para formatação eu uso o [numeral.js](https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js).

No seu caso você precisaria apenas do numeral.js e do plugin que você já usa para colher os dados do usuário, dentro da formatação específica do seu sistema.

Utilizando o numeral.js seu código fica assim;

```js
(function () {
    // Esse código é para configurar para pt-br, afinal não tem como o numeral.js
    // "descobrir do nada" qual formatação você quer
    var language = {
        delimiters: {
            thousands: '.',
            decimal: ','
        },
        abbreviations: {
            thousand: 'mil',
            million: 'milhões',
            billion: 'b',
            trillion: 't'
        },
        ordinal: function (number) {
            return 'º';
        },
        currency: {
            symbol: 'R$'
        }
    };

    // Node
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        module.exports = language;
    }
    // Browser
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && this.numeral && this.numeral.language) {
        this.numeral.language('pt-br', language);
    }
}());

numeral.language('pt-br');

var valor = new numeral(859.385).format('$ 0,0.000'); //Esse é o código que você precisa
document.write(valor);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/1.4.5/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

**PS.:** Experimente trocar o formatador para `$ 0,0.00` e ver como não é introduzido nenhum erro de arredondamento.

**PS2.:** Uma outra grande vantagem de se utilizar o numeral.js é que naturalmente o seu sistema já nasce pronto para [internacionalização (i18n)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internacionaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%28software%29)

Comment: você poderia me mostrar como aplicar esse plugin na formatação de uma coluna do [link] https://datatables.net [/link] ? , exemplo: `"aoColumns": [ { "sName": "ValorUnitario", "mData": "ValorUnitario", "sWidth": "10%" },`.

Comment: @AdrianoSUV você vai usar o método `{ render: function(numeroSemFormatacao) { return formatar(numeroSemFormatacao); } }`

Answer (score 2):

Existem alguns modos de transformar isso em moeda.

### Plugin externo

Você pode usar o plugin do Google Code, formatcurrency para fazer isso, baixe ele aqui: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/

### Por código

Outra maneira é usar regex ou então código JS para fazer.

Via jQuery:

```
$(".totalSum").text('$' + parseFloat(total, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\,)/g, "$1.").toString());
```

(Você pode checar aas respostas [deste tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043650/how-can-i-correctly-format-currency-using-jquery))

Comment: Definindo `total=56826.497` Seu código me resulta `"56,826.50"` o que estaria "incorreto" para esta pergunta, ou seja, fora do formato correto de milhar(pontos) e vírgula, do qual está no titulo da pergunta, e também no conteúdo da pergunta você pode ler `"e mostrar na tela o valor 56.826,497"` e notar que seu resultado está invertido.

Comment: É só você inverter o ponto com a virgula no regex

Comment: Mas o que estou dizendo é que para que esta seja uma resposta **válida** você já deveria ter feito isso, entende?

Comment: Entendo, mas as respostas tem intuito de ajudar o máximo possível, o resto vai do usuário poder interpretar o código e incorporar o mesmo em sua aplicação. Creio que esta resposta seja válida, pois seu problema foi resolvido, detalhes de exibição e pormenores podem ser ajustados dentro da sua aplicação. De qualquer forma vou editar por motivos de pesquisa de outros usuários também.

Comment: Usar `toFixed` com dinheiro é cilada! Existem problemas bem conhecidos de arredondamento com `toFixed`. E outro detalhe, o parseFloat só recebe um parametro. O radix é apenas para o `parseInt`. Eu sugiro uma biblioteca como o [bigmoney.js](https://github.com/demchenkoe/bigmoney.js) se você pretende fazer qualquer calculo financeiro. Alem do mais ele tem uma funcinalidade de formatacao que pode ser util

Comment: Outra biblioteca que pode ser útil é o [numeral.js](https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js)

Comment: muito obrigado. ajudou bastante