# Tabela Calculadora PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Não sei programar em `javascript` então gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês,  de como proceder nesse caso.
  Nesse código abaixo gostaria de saber como faço uma calculadora dinâmica,
  por linha, igual ao exemplo abaixo. eu só tenho que colocar a quantidade:
[image: Exemplo de Imagem]

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-primary">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 20%;" >Cod</th>
        <th style="width: 20%;">Data</th>
        <th style="width: 10%;">Tipo</th>
        <th style="width: 5%;">Quantidade</th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 14%;">Valor | Desconto</th>
        <th class="text-center" style="width: 14%;">Valor Total</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?

$cmd = "SELECT * FROM cotacao";      
    $produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
    $total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {

$valor = $linha['valor'];
$data_abertura = $linha['data_abertura'];
$cod = $linha['cod'];

?>
        <tr class="selectable">
        <td class="center"><?echo $cod?></span></td>
        <td class="center"><?echo $data_abertura?></td>

        <td class="center"><?echo $p_tipo_veiculo?></td>
        <td class="center"><input type="text" name="qtd" /></td>
        <td class="text-center">
        <font size="3.5"> <input type="text" value="<?echo $valor?>" />        
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
        <input type="text" name="total" value="resultado" />
        </td>
        </tr>

        <?}?>


       </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
function getClosest(el, tagName) {
    while (el = el.parentNode) {
        if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) return el;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    // caso não seja o input pretendido
    if (e.target.name != 'qtd' || e.target.tagName != 'INPUT') return;

    // ir buscar o valor inserido
    var value = parseFloat(e.target.value);

    // ir buscar o outro valor dentro da mesma linha
    var tr = getClosest(e.target, 'tr');
    var valor = tr.querySelector('input[name="valor"]');

    // calcular a soma
    var sum = value + parseFloat(valor.value);

    // inserir a soma no input total da mesma linha
    tr.querySelector('input[name="total"]').value = sum;
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/mxjfLu1x/

Deixei comentários no código. A função `getClosest()` é para subir no DOM e ir buscar o `tr` para ir buscar depois inputs que estão na mesma linha.

Repara que adicionei no HTML `name="valor"` no input do meio. Assim facilita e simplifica a encontrar esse input.

Coloquei o oscultador de eventos no `window` pois tenho a sensação que essa tabela é dinamica e saaim não tens de te preocupar com delegação.

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo que preciso, mais to com um probleminha. é que tenho que colocar o name="valor" com []  ficaria assim name="valor[]"  name="qtd[]"  name="total[]"  mais ai, para de fazer o caulculo como posso acertar isso?

Comment: @FabioHenrique nesse caso é só acrescentar `[]` nas strings do código -> http://jsfiddle.net/mxjfLu1x/1/

Comment: Eu tinha feito isso mais não tinha funcionado....    Agora ta funcionando perfeitamente. Blz

Comment: Parceiro...Voce saberia me informar como faço para que total apareça formatado exemplo 0.00,00 –

Comment: @FabioHenrique dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/129

Answer (score 0):

Ta um pouco confuso mas acho que entendi.

Primeiro, para múltiplos inputs, você coloca assim:

```
<input type="text" name="qtd[]" />
```

Depois você recupera os valores novamente dentro do seu while para somar com o que precisa:

```
<?

$cmd = "SELECT * FROM cotacao";      
$produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
$total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);

$i = 0; //inicia o contador    

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {

    $valor = $linha['valor'];
    $data_abertura = $linha['data_abertura'];
    $cod = $linha['cod'];

    $resultado = $_POST["qtd"][$i] + $valor; // aqui ta o resultado
    $i++; //incrementa o contador para pegar o próximo valor

?>
```

Depois você exibe o resultado:

```
<input type="text" name="total" value="<?echo $resultado?>" />
```

Comment: Ola Essa parte [] array eu sei como fazer a minha dificuldade e no calculo dinâmico quando eu colocar um numero no primeiro campo e fazer o resultado do calculo instantaneamente no ultimo campo

Comment: Entendi, então acredito que o @Sergio respondeu sua pergunta