# Convertendo valores para cálculo em JQ

Tags: jquery, html5

Como posso converter o valor de um input `1,11` para `1.11`, para poder ser somado a outros valores? Isso em jQuery.

O meu input está com máscara para valores em reais.

Comment: "para poder ser somado a outros valores" isso quer dizer que você não quer simplesmente converter de string pra string, mas pra número também, certo? E sua string de entrada tem algum ponto (tipo: `1.234,56`) ou só vírgula mesmo? (fica mais fácil se não tiver ponto nenhum no valor)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, Sim, é isso, de string para número ou valor monetário.
Cara, podem ser valores 0,01 até 1.000.000,00

Comment: Relacionado: ["Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/215)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, o link acima ajudou pouco, mas não resolveu hehehe

Comment: JQ = jQuery? Porque existe o http://stedolan.github.io/jq/ que é outra coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá pra fazer com uma linha:

```
var valorParaCalculo =  parseFloat(($(".oi").val()).replace(/\./g,"").replace(/,/g,".")); // input:999.999.999,99 - output: 999999999.99
```

Exemplo no fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zskq7cf6/1/

Comment: vou tentar essa dica que vc passou.

Comment: Consegui @Joao Paulo. Fiz umas alterações só de nome de variável, mas consegui. Aleluia!!!

Comment: Na verdade o que eu fiz pra testar se calculava, era duplicar o input do seu código, mudar os valores, é claro e fiz uma soma simples com os dois valores e deu certo.
É engraçado, hoje em dia se faz miséria e existem any frameworks em JS e pra fazer um simples cálculo, a gente apanha hehehehehe

Comment: agora encontrei um pequeno probleminha na soma.
Tenho 7 input, ou seja, somo 7 valores. O resultado dá correto, mas com com 14 zeros e 1 um, depois do resultado hehehehehe
Exemplo: 7,77000000000000001
Estou zerando todas as variáveis, antes delas receberem os valores.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer fazer cálculos com o valor do `input`, então precisa convertê-los pra número. O problema é que não dá pra guardar o número de volta pra um `input` pois ele voltaria a ser uma string (se não me engano, mesmo o `input` com tipo `number` no HTML5 ainda guarda seu valor como string), é preciso converter e usar direto.

Cada etapa é simples por si só. Em conjunto, seria:

```
var valorComVirgula = $(meuInput).val(); // "1.000.000,00"
var valorSemPonto = valorComVirgula.replace(/\./g, ""); // "1000000,00"
var valorComPonto = valorSemPonto.replace(/,/g, "."); // "1000000.00"
var valorNumerico = parseFloat(valorComPonto); // 1000000
```

E se quiser colocar o número de volta no `input` como string:

```
$(meuInput).val(valorComPonto);
```

Comment: Blz, vou tentar.

Comment: @Sergio Ops, é mesmo, estava com a questão dos valores monetários na cabeça (onde eu sempre represento por inteiros, em centavos) e esqueci que nesse caso se está usando ponto flutuante. Valeu!

Comment: Pessoa, agora encontrei um pequeno probleminha na soma. Tenho 7 input, ou seja, somo 7 valores. O resultado dá correto, mas com com 14 zeros e 1 um, depois do resultado hehehehehe Exemplo: 7,77000000000000001 Estou zerando todas as variáveis, antes delas receberem os valores.

Comment: @GustavoSevero Hehe e é *por isso* que não se deve usar ponto flutuante para fazer cálculos com unidades monetárias. :) Dá uma olhada na pergunta que eu mencionei nos comentários, infelizmente não existe solução fácil pra isso não.

Comment: eu até consegui corrigir o problema colocando .toFixed(2) depois da variável do valor.
Mas agradeço mesmo assim.