# Arredondando um número decimal para um número decimal mais baixo

Tags: javascript, matemática

Utilizando JavaScript como posso arredondar um número decimal com várias casas decimais para um número com duas casas decimais sendo o número decimal mais baixo? Exemplo:

```
44,97714285714286
```

Para

```
44,97
```

Já utilizei o `Math.floor` porém este arredonda para o número inteiro mais baixo, em que o valor fica `44` e outras maneiras que não funcionaram e se tratando em valores monetários preciso ter precisão.

Comment: Uma referência aqui no SOpt sobre como tratar dinheiro em JavaScript: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/129

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se queres arredondar por baixo basta adicionar 2 casa decimais (`* 100`), fazer `Math.floor` e depois dividir por 100 de novo.

Para arredondar para cima podes usar o `.toFixed()`, ou seja `(49.599).toFixed(2)` dá `49.60` mas acho que não é isso que queres.

Assim, uma versão mais simples de como encurtar as casas decimais, por baixo:

```
function arredondar(nr) {
    if (nr.indexOf(',') != -1) nr = nr.replace(',', '.');
    nr = parseFloat(nr) * 100;
    return Math.floor(nr) / 100;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/voxnmfm2/

Se quiseres uma função que aceite como argumento o numero de casa podes fazer assim:

```
function arredondar(str, casas) {
    if (str.indexOf(',') != -1) str = str.replace(',', '.');
    if (!casas) casas = 0;
    casas = Math.pow(10, casas);
    str = parseFloat(str) * casas;
    return Math.floor(str) / casas;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/voxnmfm2/1/

Answer (score 8):

Você pode usar o [.toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) para definir quantas casas decimais quer.

Veja um exemplo:

```
var numObj = 12345.6789;

numObj.toFixed();       // Returns '12346'
numObj.toFixed(1);      // Returns '12345.7'
numObj.toFixed(6);      // Returns '12345.678900'
(1.23e+20).toFixed(2);  // Returns '123000000000000000000.00'
(1.23e-10).toFixed(2);  // Returns '0.00'
2.34.toFixed(1);        // Returns '2.3'
-2.34.toFixed(1);       // Returns -2.3
(-2.34).toFixed(1);     // Returns '-2.3'
```

Answer (score 7):

Faça assim:

```js
console.log(Math.floor(44.97714285714286 * 100) / 100);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/Round.js).

Answer (score 3):

Caso você queira x casas depois da vírgula, você pode fazer assim:

```
function arred(d,casas) { 
   var aux = Math.pow(10,casas)
   return Math.floor(d * aux)/aux
}
```

Depois basta chamar a função. Exemplos:

```
arred(44.97714285714286,0) //44
arred(44.97714285714286,1) //44.9
arred(44.97714285714286,2) //44.97
arred(44.97714285714286,3) //44.977
arred(44.97714285714286,4) //44.9771
```