# Calculo por número impar - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu estou tentando dividir 100 por um numero, assim consigo a
porcentagem desse numero para jogar em uma variável que está
dentro de um FOR... e esse FOR joga a porcentagem dentro
de um Array... Mais ou menos Assim:

```
var numero = 4

var percentual = 100/numero

var somaPercentual = new Array();

for(i=0;i<numero;i++){

    var porcentagem = percentual

    somaPercentual.push(porcentagem)

}
```

Nesse caso meu Array viria :

25,25,25,25

Então eu preciso somar os valores do Array e dar 100!
Até aqui tudo bem... a dor de cabeça começa quando o numero que será dividido por 100 é um número Impar!

Se a variável numero é igual a 3 por exemplo, meu Array daria = 33.33, 33.33, 33.33, onde a soma daria 99.99.... e aí bagunça tudo ! 
Isso sempre acontece quando o numero é impar.

Alguem pode me dar uma luz?

[EDIT]
Resolvi usando o .Reduce() :

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var number = document.querySelector('input').value;
  var percentage = 100 / number
  var somaPercentual = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    i < number - 1 ?
      somaPercentual.push(percentage) :
      somaPercentual.push(100 - somaPercentual.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a + b
      }));
  }

  console.log(somaPercentual)
  console.log(somaPercentual.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b
  }))
})
<input type="number" value="3" />
<button>calc</button>
```

Comment: Você precisa exatamente de que? De valores inteiros?

Comment: isso @ThiagoHenrique

Comment: Tenta arredondar o resultado da soma: Math.round(somaPercentual.push(porcentagem))

Comment: Mas está a tentar fazer o que exatamente ? Ver as parcelas que 100 dividido por outro numero dá ?  Se fosse 100 por 3, quais seriam as parcelas que você quer obter ? É que para esse objetivo nem precisa de um for, basta `new Array(num).fill(100/num)` em que se `num` for 4 dá lhe  `[25, 25, 25, 25]`

Comment: Para entender melhor o proposito... eu estou mandando dados para um sistema, e esse sistema só aceita o campo "percentual" se a soma de todos os campos "percentual" der 100 ! Consegui resolver usando o .Reduce()

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso você pode usar o [Math.ceil](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp) para arredondar para cima, como sempre vai faltar algumas frações isso resolve seu problema.

Utilizei [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78507/77723) para resolver o problema do arredondamento/corte de casas decimais.

```js
var numero = 7

var percentual = 100/numero

var somaPercentual = new Array();

for(i=0;i<numero;i++){
    var porcentagem = Math.floor(percentual * 100) / 100; 
    somaPercentual.push(porcentagem)
};

var soma = 0;

for(i=0;i<somaPercentual.length;i++){
    console.log(somaPercentual[i]);
    soma += somaPercentual[i];
}

soma = Math.ceil(soma); //Math.ceil retorna o maior inteiro mais próximo (2.4 = 3)

console.log(soma);
```

Comment: Para `numero = 7`, o resultado será 101.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss valida para mim se ta certinho?

Comment: @A.Júnior a soma deve sempre retornar 100. Pois pode haver algum caso onde a soma = 99.4 se usar Round vai retornar 99 e não 100.

Comment: Tem razão. Não entendi ainda o propósito disso, mas de repente na solução utilizando o Math.ceil, colocar uma condicional para "travar" em 100 caso passe de 100.

Comment: Para entender melhor o proposito... eu estou mandando dados para um sistema, e esse sistema só aceita o campo "percentual" se a soma de todos os campos "percentual" der 100 ! 

Consegui resolver usando o .Reduce()

Answer (score 0):

Cara, se dividir 100 pra 3 vai dar sim 33.33, arredondando pra baixo, daria 33% pra cada. É impossível esse lance de dar sempre 100, não faz sentido.

Pra arredondar pra baixo você pode usar o `Math.floor()`

```js
let a = 100/3
    let b = 100 % 3;
    console.log(Math.floor(a) + '% o resultado e sobram ' + b + '%');
```

O que você pode fazer é exatamente isso, pegar o resto e somar em algum indice se sua array:

```js
var numero = 3

var percentual = 100/numero

var somaPercentual = new Array();

for(i=0;i<numero;i++){

    var porcentagem = percentual

    somaPercentual.push(Math.floor(porcentagem));

}

let somarVal = somaPercentual[somaPercentual.length - 1] + (100 % numero);

somaPercentual.push(somarVal);

console.log(somaPercentual);
```

Comment: Editei pra ficar melhor e mais completa a resposta, com uma possível alternativa pra você resolver seu problema.

Comment: Para entender melhor o proposito... eu estou mandando dados para um sistema, e esse sistema só aceita o campo "percentual" se a soma de todos os campos "percentual" der 100 ! Consegui resolver usando o .Reduce()

Answer (score 0):

Expandindo um pouco na solução que colocou como *EDIT*, para dividir `100` em várias parcelas iguais não precisa de `for`. Para todos os efeitos, existem vários casos em que não vai dar para ter parcelas iguais, pois `100` não será divisível por vários números.

A lógica mais simples é dividir pelo numero que pretende para obter o valor de cada parcela, depois soma todas menos uma, a última, que fica com o valor que falta para fazer `100`.

Um exemplo dessa lógica aplicada ao seu código:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let number = document.querySelector('input').value;
 
  let parcelas = new Array(number - 1).fill(100 / number);
  let total = parcelas.reduce((acc, curr) => curr + acc, 0);
  parcelas.push(100 - total);
  console.log(parcelas);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" value="3" />
<button>calc</button>
```

O `new Array(number - 1)` cria um array logo com `number - 1` elementos, e o [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) preenche esses elementos com o valor passado. Depois o total é achado com [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).