# Formatar decimal em valor monetário

Tags: javascript

Qual *plugin* ou *lógica*  eu posso formata valores **monetário** que retornam  do banco de forma  dinâmica?

Comment: [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/91)

Comment: Apesar de a resposta estar nesse link, eu acharia legal ter outra aqui. Afinal a outra pergunta é bem mais abrangente, e lá a formatação é tratada como detalhe (e nem é tratada em todas as respostas). Aqui a pergunta é especificamente sobre formatação. Embora, Al Unser Albuquerque, seria legal você [edit] a pergunta e dizer como estão seus dados no banco, e como estão chegando no JS. São strings? São números? Floats?

Answer (score 3):

Um exemplo prático com 2 funções que simplificam a formatação de uma forma bastante genérica:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function number_format(number, decimals, dec_point, thousands_sep) {
    number = (number+'').replace(',', '').replace(' ', '');
    var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number, 
        prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals),
        sep = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
        dec = (typeof dec_point === 'undefined') ? '.' : dec_point,
        s = '',
        toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
            var k = Math.pow(10, prec);
            return '' + Math.round(n * k) / k;
        };
    // Fix for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
    s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.');
    if (s[0].length > 3) {
        s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep);
    }
    if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
        s[1] = s[1] || '';
        s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0');
    }
    return s.join(dec);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write( number_format( 5000.000000, 2, '.', ',' ) );
document.write('<br />');
document.write( number_format( 5000.000000, 2, ',', '.' ) );
document.write('<br />');
document.write( number_format( 5000.000000 ) );
document.write('<br />');
document.write( number_format( 5000.000000 ) );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

A função `number_format` é do projeto PHPJS.org: http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/

Esse projeto traduz funções PHP para a linguagem JavaScript.

A função `number_format` possui as mesmas características do original em PHP: http://php.net/number_format

A nomenclatura dos parâmetros é autosugestiva

```
number -> o número
decimals -> quantidade de casas decimais
dec_point -> caracter representativo para as casas decimais
thousands_sep -> caracter representativo para casa de milhares
```

Importante estar ciente de que não estamos falando em regras de negócio.

Exemplo, ao formatar um valor decimal definido para ser apresentado sem as casas decimais, avalie se o modelo de negócio exige arredondamento para mais ou para menos. Nesses casos, é preciso implementar com as funções `ceil()` ou `floor()` ou, o que for mais adequado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom eu fiz uma função na mão mesmo vou postar os dois casos, *float* para *moeda*, e *moeda* para *float*:

```
custom = {};

custom.convertFloatToMoeda=function(result){
    var neg=false;
        if(result == null){ return "0,00"; }

        for (i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            if (result.toString().charAt(i)==','){ return alert('erro convertFloatToMoeda =>' +result+' nao é tipo float' ); }
            if (result.toString().charAt(i)=='-'){ neg=true; }
        }

        array = result.toString().split('.');
        result = array[0];
        var ponto = result.length;

        if(neg == true){
            while( ponto > 3 ){
                ponto = ponto - 3;
                result = splice( result,ponto, 0, "." );
                result = result.replaceAll('-.','-');
            }
        }
        else{
            while( ponto > 3 ){            
                ponto = ponto - 3;
                result = splice( result,ponto, 0, "." );
            }
        }

        var tam = array.length; //tamanho do array (para ver se tem decimais)
        if(tam > 1){            //caso tenha decimais
            if(array[1].length <= 1){       //caso tenha um digito tipo 10,3 (virgula trinta)
                array[1] = array[1] + '0';
            }
            return result + ',' + array[1]; //decimais
        }
        return result+',00'; //retorna decimais zerados se nao houver decimais
};

/**
 * @param {type} String, recebe  no formato xxx.xxx,00
 * @returns {type } String formato xxx.xxx
 */
custom.convertNumero=function(result){
var neg=false;
        if(result == null){ return "0,00"; }

        for (i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            if (result.toString().charAt(i)==','){ return alert('erro convertFloatToMoeda =>' +result+' nao é tipo float' ); }
            if (result.toString().charAt(i)=='-'){ neg=true; }
        }

        array = result.toString().split('.');
        result = array[0];
        var ponto = result.length;

        if(neg == true){
            while( ponto > 3 ){
                ponto = ponto - 3;
                result = splice( result,ponto, 0, "." );
                result = result.replaceAll('-.','-');
            }
        }
        else{
            while( ponto > 3 ){            
                ponto = ponto - 3;
                result = splice( result,ponto, 0, "." );
            }
        }
        return result; 
};
```

Claro que poderíamos trazer ele já formatado na própria consulta sql, no caso vou demonstrar em *mysql*:

```
select format(suaColuna,2,'de_DE') from suaTabela;
```