# mudar o tipo da saída para moeda

Tags: mysql

Tenho um código que me dá duas colunas, Despesa e Total, o que eu não consigo é que na saida dos totais ele me dê em formato de moeda (R$ 1.000,00).
o código é esse:

```
SELECT    nome_evento AS Despesa, SUM(saida_caixa) AS total
FROM      genius.caixa
LEFT JOIN genius.eventos ON eventos.id = id_despesa
WHERE     `data_caixa` BETWEEN "2016-07-29" AND "2016-08-30"
AND       `saida_caixa`!= 0
GROUP BY  id_despesa;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não está claro em qual das colunas quer aplicar a formatação, portanto mostrarei uma forma genérica:

```
SELECT FORMAT(12332.2, 2,'pt_BR');
```

O resultado é `12332,20`. (Sem os pontos)

Referência: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Explicando melhor

O primeiro parâmetro é o valor, o segundo é a quantidade de casas decimais. O terceiro é opcional, onde pode definir a localidade.

No exemplo apliquei o local para português do Brasil.

Para o seu caso presumo que ficaria assim:

```
FORMAT(SUM(saida_caixa), 2,'pt_BR') AS total
```

## Sugestão

Não sei onde pretende exibir os dados mas se for exibir numa página HTML, sugiro pensar em deixar o custo do processamento para o cliente, com JavaScript. Consulte esse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81554/4793

Saliento que é uma sugestão superficial e não quer dizer que é a melhor forma e tampouco a única. A melhor forma depende de cada caso.

Comment: O resultado é sem o ponto.

Comment: Caso o locale `pt_BR` não funcione você pode tentar com o `de_DE`, [nesse teste aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/452fe7/2/1) me parece equivalente ao formato pt_BR, *pelo menos na formatação de numero*.