# Conta matemática com precisão exata retorna valor diferente no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte operação matemática, e o pior, é que essa operação manipula valores monetários.

```
3898.95 / 3.0
```

Se você fizer essa operação na calculadora o resultado vai ser igual a: `1299,65` exatos.

Porém com o JavaScript o resultado vai ser igual a: `1299,649999999999`, só colocar essa operação em um alert que vocês irão ver o resultado.

E na minha aplicação aceita apenas 2 números decimais depois da vírgula e trunca o restante com a utilização de um filter no AngularJS, ou seja, em um parcelamento sempre vai faltar alguns centavos já que o resultado vai ser `1299,64`.

Filter no AngularJS:

```
app.filter("currencyRounded",function(){    
    return function(val){
        return truncateDecimals(val, 2);
    }
});
```

Funções que a execução do filter chama:

```
function truncateDecimals (num, digits) {
    if (num == undefined) num = 0.0;
    var numS = num.toString(),
        decPos = numS.indexOf('.'),
        substrLength = decPos == -1 ? numS.length : 1 + decPos + digits,
        trimmedResult = numS.substr(0, substrLength),
        finalResult = isNaN(trimmedResult) ? 0 : trimmedResult;

    return formatOnlyNumber(parseFloat(finalResult)).replace(/\./g,',');
}

function formatOnlyNumber(valor){
    return parseFloat(Math.round(valor * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
}
```

Mas a questão principal é, como ter `1299,65` como resultado? Se for apenas utilizando JavaScript sem nenhuma outra função melhor ainda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplique seu valor por 100, tornando suas casas decimais em inteiros. Arredonde utilizando o `Math.round()`, eliminando os decimais, e divida o resultado por 100, recuperando os decimais.

```
console.log(Math.round(1299.649999999999 * 100) / 100);
```

Você também pode optar por utilizar o `Math.floor()` (arredondamento sempre para baixo) ou o `Math.ceil()` (arredondamento sempre pra cima).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
var n = this, 
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
   return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
 };


new Number(3898.95 / 3.0 ).formatMoney(2,',','.');
```

Apesar de eu mesmo ter marcado como duplicada, mas talvez você não tenha entendido como usar a função, então ta ai em cima.

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11267/12032

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, nesse caso retorna como String e incluindo os pontos e vírgulas juntos, porém a função realiza cálculos e será muito útil utilizar o que você passou quando o resultado será exibido na tela.

Comment: A função demonstrada na pergunta retorna valores numéricos. Não há necessidade de se manipular string quando há métodos matemáticos que atendem esta necessidade.

Comment: @MFedatto passei um exemplo por causa da mascara de milhar e casas decimais(português é com virgula e não ponto) você tratou apenas o arredondamento, neste ponto esta certo em usar apenas funções nativas.