# Como fazer cálculos em Javascript aceitando vírgula para separar casas decimais

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um app onde em campos que aceitarem decimais, o cliente pode colocar a vírgula ao invés de ponto (que é o comum visualmente). Qual a melhor forma de eu transformar uma string `"12,34"` em um numeral como `12.34`?

Comment: Você pensa em alterar no núcleo do JS?

Comment: Viste esta pergunta e respostas? -> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/129

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vamos supor que o valor formatado em dinheiro seja: **R$ 1.234,53**

No exemplo acima você terá ponto e vírgula, neste caso, se usar o `.replace(',','.')`, seu número de saída seria algo assim: **1.234**, mas o correto deveria ser **1234.53**. Pense agora na casa de milhares (**1.000.000.000,00**), quantas formatações precisariam..., então seria ideal que tivesse uma regra geral para todo mundo, evitando futuros transtornos, você pode criar um método da seguinte maneira, independente do valor de entrada:

```
//em float
formatNumber(1234.53);
//em string real
formatNumber('1.234,53');
//em string real sem ponto
formatNumber('1234,53');
//em string americano
formatNumber('1,234.53');

//retornará 1234.53
function formatNumber(value) {
    value = convertToFloatNumber(value);
    return value.formatMoney(2, '.', '');
}
//retornará 1.234,53
function formatNumber(value) {
    value = convertToFloatNumber(value);
    return value.formatMoney(2, ',', '.');
}
//retornará 1,234.53
function formatNumber(value) {
    value = convertToFloatNumber(value);
    return value.formatMoney(2, '.', ',');
}

 //transforma a entrada em número float
 var convertToFloatNumber = function(value) {
     value = value.toString();
      if (value.indexOf('.') !== -1 && value.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
          if (value.indexOf('.') <  value.indexOf(',')) {
             //inglês
             return parseFloat(value.replace(/,/gi,''));
          } else {
            //português
             return parseFloat(value.replace(/./gi,'').replace(/,/gi,'.'));
          }      
      } else {
         return parseFloat(value);
      }
   }

//prototype para formatar a saída  
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function (c, d, t) {
    var n = this,
        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
        d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
        t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
        i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};
```

Answer (score 14):

Use os seguintes métodos do Javascript

- [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) para trocar a virgula por ponto
- [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) para converter para float/double
- [toFixed](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) para definir quantas casas decimais você quer após a virgula

```js
var string1 = '21,21';
var string2 = '10,8';

var numero1 = parseFloat(string1.replace(',', '.'));
var numero2 = parseFloat(string2.replace(',', '.'));

document.write('Número 1: <b>' + numero1 + '</b><br />');
document.write('Número 2: <b>' + numero2 + '</b><br />');
document.write('Soma: <b>' + (numero1 + numero2).toFixed(2) + '</b><br />');
```

Comment: vlw mas já tinha sido respondida anteriormente

Comment: @LeandroLUK a primeira resposta foi a minha, mas tudo bem, o importante é resolver seu problema. :)

Answer (score 8):

Pode utilizar o `replace` onde você delimita o caracter a ser substituído e depois passá-lo para `float`:

```
var comVigula = "1,87";
comVirgula = parseFloat(comVirgula.replace(',','.'));
alert(comVirgula);
```

Após isto é só utilizar como quiser em seu código.

Answer (score 1):

Só complementando a resposta do Ivan Ferrer, na linha:

```
            //português
         return parseFloat(value.replace(/./gi,'').replace(/,/gi,'.'));
```

Ficou faltando o "\." para escapar o ".". Ajustando ficaria assim:

```
            //português
         return parseFloat(value.replace(/\./gi,'').replace(/,/gi,'.'));
```

Com ajuste, funcionou perfeito para mim.

Answer (score 1):

Eu suponho que você queira fazer alguns calculos com os numeros que seus clientes colocam e também acho que você deve querer salvar alguns valores na sua database. Então seria bom que ficasse padronizado e em todos os lugares você salvasse o número mesmo(Ex. 123123123 ao invez de 123.123.123) e apenas quando fosse mostrar para o seu cliente você colocaria as virgulas e os pontos que precisassem.

Desse modo, você pode usar as funções tanto na database como no seu backend como no seu front end e claramento so precisará mudar algo quando for mostrar pro seu criente.

Se você quiser colocar pontos e virgulas também, por examplo 123.232,32
Eu uso a seguinte função: (Vale lembrar que ela foi feita para preços de produtos, se você realmente quiser apenas trocar virgulas por pontos e pontos por virgulas é melhor usar num.replace(',', '.'))

```
function brl_comma_dot(num){
    var num_1 = parseInt(num);//Pega a parte inteira do numero
    var num_2 = Math.round((num-num_1)*100);//Pega a parte nao inteira
    var digits = [];
    while(num_1 >= 1){//Enquanto a parte inteira for maior que 1
        var digit = num_1 % 10;
        digits.push(digit);//Guarda cada digito neste array em ordem contraria
        num_1 = Math.floor(num_1/10);
    }
    num_1 ="";
    //Para todos os numeros no array adiciona "." a cada 3 numeros
    for(var i = 0; i< digits.length; i++){a 
        if( i % 3 == 0 && i != 0){
            var comma = '.';
        }else{
            var comma = '';
        }
        num_1 = digits[i]+ comma +num_1;
    }

    if(num_2 < 10 && num_2 != 0){
        num_2 = "0" + num_2;
    }else if(num_2 == 0){
        num_2 = "00";
    }else if(num_2 % 10 == 0 && num_2 !=0){
        num_2 = num_2/10;
        num_2 = num_2+"0";
    }
    if(num_1 == 0){
        num_1 = "0";
    }
    var num_with_comma = num_1+","+num_2;
    return num_with_comma;
}
```