# Calcular com com virgula e ponto com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Pessoal como que eu calculo exemplo 1.400 + 1.400 gostaria que o resultado fosse o seguinte resultado = 2.800 e nao 2.8 alguém pode me ajuda ai ?

```js
  $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
                var val = $($(this)).val().replace(',','.');
                $($(this)).val(val);
                $('#result').val(Number($('input[name="number_01"]').val()) + Number($('input[name="number_02"]').val()));
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
          <label for="">Peso 01: </label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="number_01" id="number_01"><br>
          <label for="">Peso 02: </label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="number_02" id="number_02"><br><br>
          <label for="">Resultado: </label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="result" id="result">
</form>
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101773/como-fazer-c%C3%A1lculos-em-javascript-aceitando-v%C3%ADrgula-para-separar-casas-decimais - Isto vai te ajudar imenso. Era uma pequena pesquisa antes e já estava resolvido. Cumps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente fazer as modificações abaixo no seu código que funcionará do modo desejado.

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
    //Receber os 2 valores, substituir vírgulas por ponto (replace) e converter para float (decimal)
    var num1 = parseFloat($('#number_01').val().replace(',','.'));
    var num2 = parseFloat($('#number_02').val().replace(',','.'));
    //Somar os valores digitados e exibir o resultado preservando 3 dígitos após o ponto
    $('#result').val((num1 + num2).toFixed(3));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
          <label for="">Peso 01: </label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="number_01" id="number_01"><br>
          <label for="">Peso 02: </label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="number_02" id="number_02"><br><br>
          <label for="">Resultado: </label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="result" id="result">
</form>
```