# Ajax - Parametro tipo Float

Tags: ajax, json, float, tipagem

Ola, estou precisando de uma ajudinha com ajax, creio que seja coisa boba porem estou tendo bastante dificuldade e não encontrei nada relacionado na internet sobre o mesmo, preciso passar parametro do ajax para minha controller, porem do tipo float, criei um objeto json para tentar conseguir receber o valor tipo float, porem nem com objeto nem com valor explicito eu consigo passar tipo float, apenas string e tipo int.

Segue abaixo minha funcao Ajax, onde crio um objeto e envio valores, sendo que vlTotalLiquido, vlUnitario, são valores do tipo float por se tratar de dinheiro, mas nessa parte desconsidero por que jquery não e uma linguagem tipada mas o valor esta certo como desejo enviar, EXEMPLO: 2,00

```
var Objeto = new Object();
        Objeto.idProduto = idProduto;
        Objeto.IdPreVenda = parseInt($("#idPreVenda").val());
        Objeto.qtItem = parseInt($("#qtItem").val());
        Objeto.vlUnitario = parseFloat($("#vlUnitario").val());
        Objeto.prDesconto = parseFloat($("#prDesconto").val());
        Objeto.vlTotalLiquido = parseFloat($("#ValorComDesconto").val());    


$.ajax(
{

    url: "/ItPreVenda/SalvarItens",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: Objeto,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Resultado > 0)
            alert('sucesso');
            ListarItens(idprevenda);
    }
});
```

Abaixo segue o codigo da minha controller, estou recebendo em meu Objeto todos os valores tipo INT mas os valores tipo float nao consigo receber!

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SalvarItens(ItPreVenda Objeto)
        {
            //ainda irei tratar os valores
            return Json(Objeto);
        }
```

Caso alguem saiba um modo de se fazer isso agradeco, OBRIGADO e UM FELIZ ANO NOVO A TODOS!

Comment: Porque não tiras os `parseFloat` e envias strings para o servidor? Quando tens `2,00` em type Number isso vai ser só `2`.

Comment: E acho que deves dar uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade, tudo o que você colocar no JSON tecnicamente acaba virando uma string que será passada para sua controller.

Sendo assim, a única coisa que você precisaria fazer, é converter essa string para float no seu backend.

Comment: Opa Andre tudo bom cara? Obrigado pelo feedback, porém eu tive essa ideia de usar o Convert.ToFloat, porem quando eu recebo a minha string "2.00" e converto para float ele me retorna 200 e sendo assim nao consigo trabalhar com esse valor por se tratar de dinheiro!

Comment: Beleza e voce?! Tente trabalhar com decimal ao invés de float, pois nesse caso voce precisaria de poucas casas decimais, e o decimal creio que seria mais apropriado... Não estou conseguindo reproduzir aqui o output com 200... Talvez por causa da Region do meu Visual Studio... 

Tente trabalhar com recurso de Culture pra ele converter corretamente o valor considerando o "." como um divisor de decimal.

Comment: Graças a Deus tudo bem, cara tentei o decimal tambem porem quando coloco minha controller pra receber o valor decimal valor, ela não e chamada, por que o ajax tem que passar todos os valores do modo certo(nao entendi bem esse detalhe do ajax) porem nem acionou minha controller, vou ver essa conversao com recurso do culture e te dou um feedback

Comment: Coloca aqui o bloco de código no qual você esta recebendo as variáveis vindas do ajax, por favor... Ai talvez possamos encontrar o problema.

Comment: esta la em cima, recebo um Objeto json

Comment: Você não consegue acessar as propriedades do JSON passado?

Tenta chamar assim:     string variavel = Context.Request["nomeDaPropriedade"];