# Calcular o resto de uma divisão de números decimais em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matemática, decimal, valor-monetário, divisão

Estou trabalhando com valores (`decimal(18,2)`) de uma venda onde a soma do preço dos produtos deve se transformar em um determinado número de parcelas. Para que eu consiga dividir o total dos produtos exatamente para as parcelas, eu preciso também calcular a sobra da divisão e então aplicar esta sobra a uma única parcela final. Para isso eu faço:

```
var parcelas = 3;
var produtos = [
    {nome: 'bola', valor: 10},
    {nome: 'pipa', valor: 5.3},
    {nome: 'carro', valor: 15}
]; 

//total dos produtos (resultado = 30.3 ~> R$30,30)
var total = 0;
for(var i in produtos){
  total = total + produtos[i].valor;
}

//verifico se há resto na divisão
var restoDivisao = total % parcelas
```

Quando eu verifico se há o resto na divisão, ele está retornando `0.30` mas se eu divido `30.3 / 3` o resultado é `10.1`.

Qual a forma correta para que eu verifique se há resto em uma divisão com valores decimais?

Fazendo testes, de certa forma eu consegui fazer assim:

```
var restoDivisao = (((total) * 100) % parcelas) / 100;
```

Esse jeito funciona mas não consigo aceitar que realmente não exista um método mais "limpo" do que esse. Existe uma forma mais visualmente correta para chegar no resto desta divisão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta função simples resolve o problema

```
function getValorParcelas(precoTotal,numeroParcelas){
    var valorParcela            = parseFloat(precoTotal/numeroParcelas).toFixed(2);
    var valorPrimeiraParcela    = precoTotal-(valorParcela*(numeroParcelas-1));

    return { 'valor_primeira_parcela': valorPrimeiraParcela , 'valor_parcela': valorParcela, 'numero_parcelas': numeroParcelas };
}
```

Para recuperar os dados:

```
var parcelaObj = getValorParcelas(100,3);
alert(parcelaObj.valor_primeira_parcela);
alert(parcelaObj.valor_parcela);
alert(parcelaObj.numero_parcelas);
```

Answer (score 10):

Você acaba de descobrir o que todo programador deveria saber antes de fazer um código que lida com dinheiro. Os valores "decimais" na verdade são binários e não são exatos. Para grande parte das coisas que precisam de valores não inteiros esta inexatidão não importa muito, com dinheiro e alguns outros tipos de dados importa. O JavaScript por padrão trabalha com o valor em binário.

Talvez não tenha erro no algoritmo mas não vou dizer que a operação está certa porque **não vi todo o código que distribui as parcelas**. A não ser que seja só isto. Aí eu não entendo isto como cálculo de parcelas e há uma lógica muito errada.

Pode fazer o que quiser com dados binários que não vai resolver. Provavelmente todo seu sistema tem estes problemas e possivelmente causando erros financeiros. E não adianta resolver só este cálculo. Vai resolver neste ponto e continuar causando problema no resto do sistema. Nunca acredite em soluções que "funcionam", siga soluções certas. O que funciona pode deixar de funcionar porque ela não era certa. Sempre aprenda a certa.

Este é o maior perigo neste tipo de problema. É muito fácil achar que resolveu o problema e ele continuar existindo.

A solução é trocar o jeito como armazena e manipula todos estes dados. Algumas linguagens possuem um tipo que já ajuda nisto, outros não. Como é o caso do JS. Mas este é um "problema" de todas as linguagens.

Não vou entrar em detalhes porque já foi respondido em: [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101). Lá tem a solução usando apenas inteiros ou bibliotecas que abstrai um pouco o seu uso, mas não resolve todas as situações.

Veja também [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Li todas as respostas e não vi nenhuma adereçando a raíz do seu problema. O seu problema na verdade não está no JavaScript (ou na programação), mas sim na lógica matemática por trás da operação `Módulo`.

Para entender melhor, vamos ao modelo mais básico possível da divisão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que a primeira operação é **30 ÷ 30**, com resultado **1** e resto **3**. 
Quando você obtém o resto **0.3**, são esses **0.3** que você está adquirindo. A resposta não é **0.1**, pois **0.1** é o valor decimal da divisão, e não o resto.

Analisemos o código que você diz que funciona:

```
var restoDivisao = (((total) * 100) % parcelas) / 100;
```

Nesse caso você está pegando os valores decimais de até 2ª precisão e tornando-os inteiro (como a divisão da 2ª série te sugere fazer) e depois calculando o resto.

```
((100)*100) MOD 7) / 100 = 0,04
```

Veja que `14,28 * 7 = 99,96`, sendo o 0,04 o restante faltante para interar os R$100,00

---

Analisando um caso em que as parcelas são maiores que o valor total:

```
((8,80)*100) MOD 12) / 100 = 0,04
```

Veja que `0,73 * 12 = 8,76` faltando apenas `0,04`.

### Resumindo e calculando os valores das parcelas

```
// Altere esses valores para cada compra específica
var numeroDeParcelas = 12;
var valorTotal = 8.80;
// ------------------------------------------------

// Use esta formula para determinar os resultados
var restoDivisao = (((valorTotal) * 100) % numeroDeParcelas) / 100; // 0.040000011
var cadaParcela = Math.floor((total * 100) / parcela) / 100;  // 0.73
var ultimaParcela  = parseFloat((cadaParcela + restoDivisao).toFixed(2)) // 0.77
// --------------------------------------------
```

Resultado final:

```
0.73 * 11 = 8,03 + 0,77 = 8,80
```

Com esta fórmula você só deve garantir que será aplicado `((numeroDeParcelas - 1)*cadaParcela) + ultimaParcela` e sua venda terá o valor integral recebido, desde que seja limitado apenas a 2 casas decimais. Para aumentar o número de casas (como geralmente postos de gasolina fazem) você deve mudar o cálculo do resto da divisão para 1000 ao invés de 100.

Comment: sim dessa forma funciona mas se quando eu tenho uma referência onde o valor da soma das parcelas é maior, quando eu uso o seu cálculo ele não chega na solução, `var parcelas = 6, valor =10; var resto = (((valor) * 100) % parcelas) / 100; var cada = parseFloat((total / parcela).toFixed(2)); var ultima = parseFloat((cada + resto).toFixed(2)); //resultado ~> ((6 * cada) + ultima).toFixed(2) = 10.06 `

Comment: @LeandroLUK editei o cálculo da variável `cadaParcela` para evitar esse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Converta o decimal para int multiplicando por 100 antes da operação de módulo e dividindo depois por 100 novamente.

Comment: já tentei e até cheguei nessa solução antes de ver que você postou mas se eu faço isso eu valido somente os centavos... encontrei outra solução ja vlw

Answer (score 0):

Minha solução foi fazer o tratamento de cada conjunto de caracteres do double, e depois disso somando os mesmos. assim:

```
var restoDivisao = parseInt(total % parcelas) + (((total * 100) % parcelas) / 100);
```

**EDIT:**
A solução acima na verdade não da certo porque quando as parcelas são maiores os valores podem acabar não batendo (*graças ao probleminha que o @anieroesclareceu*), mas descobri que se for calculada a margem de erro anteriormente eu posso tratar os valores e somar/subtrair essa margem em uma última parcela, assim meu financeiro não fica errado, assim:

```
var margem = ((((total / parcelas).toFixed(2)) * parcelas) - total).toFixed(2);
```

Ao fazer isso você chega na diferença quando o valor monetário (de 2 casas) não bate com o valor original antes da divisão e a partir disso, basta somar o mesmo (em módulo) na ultima parcela gerada, assim

```
var arrayParcelas = [];
for(var i = 0, i < parcelas; i++){
    arrayParcelas.push({'id':i, 'valor': total / parcelas});
};

arrayParcelas[arrayParcelas.length - 1].valor = 
    arrayParcelas[arrayParcelas.length - 1].valor - (margem);
```

Fazendo isso, independente da margem da diferença for positiva ou negativa, a ultima parcela terá esse acerto.

Comment: Você leu minha resposta, né? Isto resolve o problema aí, o resto do seu sistema vai continuar errado. Não se representa valores decimais de forma binária como o JS faz. Ou seja, é gambiarra localizada que faz parecer que resolve o real problema.

Comment: Sim, li sua resposta e concordo plenamente com você mas no contexto que estou trabalhando essa solução foi satisfatória. =D

Comment: Então você não entendeu ela, mas não sou eu que terei prejuízos :)

Comment: cheguei na solução parceiro, que com certeza não me dá prejuízo! ;D

Comment: Ok, teimosia causa mais estrago que desconhecimento.

Answer (score -1):

Fiz uma modificação para aplicar a diferença na primeira parcela.

```
function getValorParcelas(precoTotal,numeroParcelas){
    var valorParcela            = parseFloat(precoTotal/numeroParcelas).toFixed(2);
    var valorPrimeiraParcela    = parseFloat(precoTotal-(valorParcela*(numeroParcelas-1))).toFixed(2);

    return { 'valor_primeira_parcela': valorPrimeiraParcela , 'valor_parcela': valorParcela, 'numero_parcelas': numeroParcelas };
}
```

Comment: Isso não responde completamente a pergunta.