# Casa decimal - JQuery

Tags: jquery, arredondamento

Boa tarde!
O código abaixo realiza o calculo da média, porém, dependendo do valor ele fica com dizima periódica, como arredondar os valores em casas decimais, por exemplo 0.00 ou 00.00?
Obrigado.

HTML:

```
Nota 1: <input class="nota" /><br/>
Nota 2: <input class="nota" /><br/>
Nota 3: <input class="nota" /><br/><br/>
Media: <input id="media" readonly/>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
$('.nota').change(function(){
  var total = 0;
  var notas = 0;
  $('.nota').each(function(){
      var nota = new Number(this.value);          
      if(nota === 0) return;          
      total = total + nota;
      notas++;
  })
  $('#media').val(total/notas);
  });
})
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101

Comment: Ainda não consegui fazer o arredondamento (.00), alguém tem alguma idéia para me ajudar? Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o  **.toFixed(2)**

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
//5.57
```

Comment: Perfeito @FelipeFM, Obrigado!

Comment: @Felipe FM me ajudou demais, valeu.