# Função JavaScript com erro de NaN

Tags: javascript, string, float

Essa função esta retornando erro: NaN, para converter novamente para texto.

```
function floatToMoneyText(value) {
            var text = (value < 1 ? "0" : " ") + Math.floor(value * 100);
            text = "R$ " + text;
            return text.substr(0, text.length - 2) + "," + text.substr(-2); 
        }
```

Aqui tem o link: https://jsfiddle.net/nkf3tLkq/

Comment: Qual é o objetivo desta função? Ela não parece fazer nada útil.

Comment: Tem no livro que estou lendo, eu nao entendi direito.

Comment: Me parece ser um livro bem ruim.

Comment: é para demostrar o uso das funcões, floor, substr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tome cuidado com esses livros, principalmente que tem exemplos ruins. A função em si não tinha problema, a não ser pelo fato de tentar executar algo com um argumento inválido. O problema era no dado passado, mudando para enviar um valor numérico acaba funcionando. É uma pena que um livro incentiva, mesmo que em um exercício, o [uso de valor monetário com `float`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101). Quem está aprendendo acha que isso é certo. É óbvio que o livro deve ensinar outras coisas erradas. A própria lógica de conversão destas funções é ruim.

```js
function moneyTextToFloat(text) { 
  var cleanText = text.replace("R$", " ").replace(",", ".");
  return parseFloat(cleanText);
}

function floatToMoneyText(value) {
  var text = (value < 1 ? "0" : " ") + Math.floor(value * 100);
  return "R$ " + text.substr(0, text.length - 2) + "," + text.substr(-2); 
}

var total = document.getElementById("total");
var mostrar = moneyTextToFloat(total.innerHTML);
alert(mostrar);
var mostrarTexto = floatToMoneyText(29.90);
alert(mostrarTexto);
```

```html
<body>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>R$ 29,90</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td>Total da compra</td>
      <td><div id="total">R$ 29,90</div></td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/FormatMoney.js).