# Formatação de números com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Tenho um array que é retornado por meio de uma requisição AJAX e pretendo formatar os números de cada uma dessas chaves da seguinte forma:

> Exemplo:

**Valores padrões**

```
-> 2569
-> 192544694
```

**Como gostaria que fossem formatados**

```
-> 2.569
-> 192.544.694
```

Claro que essa formatação seria por meio de uma função por se tratar de valores variáveis. Cheguei a criar uma função mas não obtive total flexibilidade em sua efetividade, além de tentar alguns frameworks, como `number.js`, por exemplo.

Alguma solução? Seja um script ou framework alternativo?

Comment: Esses numeros são numeros, ou dinheiro? (Sobre formatar dinheiro: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/129)

Comment: @Sergio, são números!

Comment: Ok, então a minha resposta deve fazer o que precisas. Dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
function formatar(nr) {
  return String(nr)
    .split('').reverse().join('').split(/(\d{3})/).filter(Boolean)
    .join('.').split('').reverse().join('');
}

var numeros = [2569, 192544694];
var formatados = numeros.map(formatar);
console.log(JSON.stringify(formatados)); // ["2.569","192.544.694"]
```

A ideia é usar uma expressão regular para agrupar de 3 em 3, mas como queremos agrupar de trás para a frente, daí a lógica do `reverse()`.

Comment: Sem espinhas, muito bom

Answer (score 2):

```
function format(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split(',');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Créditos para Abe Miessler em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting

Comment: +1 muito bom...

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo a biblioteca [jQuery mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). Seu código poderá ficar dessa forma:

**HTML**

```
<input class="money" />
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('.money').mask('0000.000,00', {reverse: true});
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/aoc6o0qa/1/

Comment: é impressão minha ou nessa biblioteca não tem formatação para números? Apesar disso, muito interessante, obrigado pela sugestão!