# Aceitar centavos em um código javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola não estou conseguindo fazer com que o Código aceite centavos segue o código javascript alguém da uma luz ai

```js
<script>
total = 0;

function adiciona(id)
{
 calcula(id,"adicao");
}

function remove(id)
{
 calcula(id,"subtracao");
}    
 
function calcula(id,operacao)
{
 nomeid  = "nome"+id;
 precoid = "preco"+id;
 qtdid   = "qtd"+id;
 
 nome  = document.getElementById(nomeid).innerHTML;
 
 preco = document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML;    
 preco = parseInt(preco);
 
 qtd   = document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML;
 qtd   = parseInt(qtd);

 //Debug
 //alert("Produto: " + nome + "\n Preço: " + preco);    
 
 if(operacao=="adicao")
 {
  total = total + preco;
  qtd = qtd + 1;
 }
 else
 {
  total = total - preco;
  qtd = qtd - 1;
 }
 
 document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML = qtd;
 document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}   
</script>

<script>
function verifica_e_envia()
{
 array_dados = new Array();
 
 colecao = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  
 qtd_blocos = colecao.length - 1; // O último tr da tabela é onde fica o total e está sendo descontado
 // É necessário saber a quantidade de blocos para poder usar em um loop catando os valores
  
 // Percorre os blocos catando nomes, quantidades e valores dos produtos com quantidade maior que zero
 for(i=1; i<=qtd_blocos ;i++)
 {
  qtdid = "qtd"+i;
  qtd   = document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML;
  qtd   = parseInt(qtd);
   
  if(qtd>0)
  {
   obj_tmp = {};
    
   nomeid = "nome"+i;
   nome   = document.getElementById(nomeid).innerHTML;
    
   precoid = "preco"+i;
   preco   = document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML;
   preco   = parseFloat(preco);

   obj_tmp.nome  = nome;
   obj_tmp.preco = preco;
   obj_tmp.qtd   = qtd;
   obj_tmp.subtotal = qtd*preco;
    
   // adiciona elemento no array de dados que será enviado
   array_dados.push(obj_tmp);
  }
 }
  
 // põe o array_dados no input hidden json_dados
 document.getElementById("json_dados").value = JSON.stringify(array_dados);
  
 // envia o formulário form_pedido_produtos
 document.getElementById("form_pedido_produtos").submit();
}
</script>
```

ascript

Comment: Você já tentou ao invés de usar `parseInt` usar `parseFloat`, e usar o ponto para separar os centavos ao invés de virgula?

Comment: Assim  preco   = parseFloat (preco.replace("," , ".") );

Comment: Onde não aceita? Você diz que ele. Ao calcula os centavos?

Comment: isso !  qaundo adiciono isso no javascript parseFloat (preco.replace("," , ".") ); porem nao faz o calculo dinamico da minha tabela

Comment: Assim funciona   preco = parseInt(preco); porem nao visualiza os centavos tipo o que é 60,40 fica somente 60

Comment: Não vai calcular mesmo. ParseInt e somente para você usar números inteiros.

Comment: Lá no começo do script da pergunta. Tira aquela declaração de parseint. Não precisa ficar formatando toda hora o valor. O valor vem com ponto ou com vírgula e quantas casas for, depois de calcular pela quantidade formata ele com preco_arredondado = parseFloat(preco.toFixed(2));

Comment: Você pode formatar ele várias vezes. Mais tenha em mente que quando multiplicar ou dividir pela quantidade ele vai gerar vais casas depois da vírgula denovo. O importante e formatar depois do cálculo. E parseint não serve para cálculos monetários ou cálculos que usam casas decimais.

Comment: valor 60,90 com virgula  coloquei assim parseFloat (preco.replace(',', '.') );  fica um ponto no lugar da virgula gostaria que fosse virgula

Comment: Vê lá Hemerson: 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11018/como-representar-dinheiro-em-javascript/175800#175800

Answer (score 2):

Amigo use `parseFloat(var.toFixed(2));`.

Exemplo:
 `var valor = 10000.100000;
var arredondado = parseFloat(valor.toFixed(2));`

Retorno 10000.10

Answer (score 1):

Cara vê só .. um professor meu me passou esse código aqui quando eu tava na facul

```
    function moeda(valor, casas, separdor_decimal, separador_milhar){ 

 var valor_total = parseInt(valor * (Math.pow(10,casas)));
 var inteiros =  parseInt(parseInt(valor * (Math.pow(10,casas))) / parseFloat(Math.pow(10,casas)));
 var centavos = parseInt(parseInt(valor * (Math.pow(10,casas))) % parseFloat(Math.pow(10,casas)));


 if(centavos%10 == 0 && centavos+"".length<2 ){
  centavos = centavos+"0";
 }else if(centavos<10){
  centavos = "0"+centavos;
 }

 var milhares = parseInt(inteiros/1000);
 inteiros = inteiros % 1000; 

 var retorno = "";

 if(milhares>0){
  retorno = milhares+""+separador_milhar+""+retorno
  if(inteiros == 0){
   inteiros = "000";
  } else if(inteiros < 10){
   inteiros = "00"+inteiros; 
  } else if(inteiros < 100){
   inteiros = "0"+inteiros; 
  }
 }
  retorno += inteiros+""+separdor_decimal+""+centavos;


 return retorno;

}
```

testa ai velho!! espero ter ajudado.