# Problema com acentos na hora de inserir um campo personlizado no painel do wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Ola amigos quando coloco ali "Hemerson Assuncao" envia mais quando coloco com caracteres acetos tipo Assunção nao envia exemplo

add_post_meta($id, 'nome_completo','Hemerson Assunção');

Alguem da essa força ai segue meu codigo completo abaixo

```html
<?php
require_once 'wp-load.php';
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';



// Cria o post
$id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title'    => 'Pedido de Gas',
        'post_content'  => $pedido,
       // 'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
       // 'post_author'   => $user_id,
        'post_type'     => 'pedidos',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
));
if ($id) {
    // criacao de categoria
   wp_set_post_terms($id, wp_create_category('gas'), 'category');
    // Campos Pesonalizados
   add_post_meta($id, 'nome_completo','Hemerson Assunção');
   add_post_meta($id, 'endereco',$endereco);
   add_post_meta($id, 'numero',$numero);
   add_post_meta($id, 'bairro',$bairro);
   add_post_meta($id, 'contato',$contato);
   add_post_meta($id, 'troco',$troco);
   add_post_meta($id, 'total',$total);


} else {
    echo "WARNING: Failed to insert post into WordPress\n";
}



?>
```

Comment: Não envia pra onde?

Comment: Qualquer coisa usa utf8_encode.

Comment: Para o painel de wordpress

Comment: Não. Aonde define-os seu nome. Faz uma variável declarando sem nome dentro da utf8_encode e testa. Tipo $nome = utf8_encode('Hemerson Assunção');

Comment: Aí onde você inseriu seu nome coloca a variável sem aspas.

Comment: Assim: <?php $nome_completo =  utf8_encode $_POST['nome_completo'];?>

Comment: Assim: <?php $nome_completo = utf8_encode($_POST['nome_completo']);?>

Comment: Se não der tenta utf8_decode

Comment: Deu certo meu diretor filé vou colocar um UP pra vc valeu obrigado!

Comment: Respondi. Da como resposta correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim: `$nome_completo = utf8_encode($_POST['nome_completo']);`

Comment: Consegui responder essa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175307/aceitar-centavos-em-um-código-javascript

Comment: Avalia a resposta aqui como certa. Você só deu like. Vou ver a outra.