# Aceitar centavos no javascript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria que esse codigo pegasse os centavos do valor vindo da variável javascript

```
preco = parseInt(preco);
```

ja coloquei assim nada

```
preco = parseFloat(preco);
```

Codigo completo abaixo

```js
total = 0;

function adiciona(id) {
    calcula(id, "adicao");
}

function remove(id) {
    calcula(id, "subtracao");
}

function calcula(id, operacao) {
    nomeid = "nome" + id;
    precoid = "preco" + id;
    qtdid = "qtd" + id;
    nome = document.getElementById(nomeid).innerHTML;

    preco = document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML;
    preco = parseInt(preco);

    qtd = document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML;
    qtd = parseInt(qtd);

    //Debug
    //alert("Produto: " + nome + "\n Preço: " + preco);    

    if (operacao == "adicao") {
        total = total + preco;
        qtd = qtd + 1;
    } else {
        total = total - preco;
        qtd = qtd - 1;
    }

    document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML = qtd;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}
```

Comment: O que dá `alert(document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML);`? e queres apanhar só a parte decimal, é isso?

Comment: por exemplo o valor esta 60,80 so aparece 60 entendeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Hemerson,

Tenta o seguinte:

```
// com preco ainda como string converte vírgula para ponto
preco.replace (", ", ". "); 

// depois converte para float
preco = parseFloat(preco);
```

E no php vai precisar usar number_format para formatar quando quiser exibir float com vírgula como casa decimal. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: isso e no php ou javascript ?

Comment: O código q escrevi acima é de javascript.  Não tenho como ver aqui seu código de ontem pra te orientar melhor levando ele em conta pq tô na casa da minha noiva escrevendo no cel...  :-]

Comment: Vamos pro chat  ?

Comment: Vou colocar o código completo abaixo

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <script>
    
     total = 0;
        
        function adiciona(id)
        {
            calcula(id,"adicao");
        }
        
        function remove(id)
        {
            calcula(id,"subtracao");
        }    
            
        function calcula(id,operacao)
        {
                nomeid  = "nome"+id;
                precoid = "preco"+id;
                qtdid   = "qtd"+id;
                
                nome  = document.getElementById(nomeid).innerHTML;
                
                preco = document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML;    
                preco = parseInt(preco); 
                
                qtd   = document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML;
                qtd   = parseInt(qtd);

                //Debug
                //alert("Produto: " + nome + "\n Preço: " + preco);    
                
                if(operacao=="adicao")
                {
                    total = total + preco;
                    qtd = qtd + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    total = total - preco;
                    qtd = qtd - 1;
                }
                
                document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML = qtd;
                
                document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
        }    
            
        
    </script>
<script>
   function verifica_e_envia()
   {
    array_dados = new Array();
   
    colecao = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    
    qtd_blocos = colecao.length - 1; // O último tr da tabela é onde fica o total e está sendo descontado
    // É necessário saber a quantidade de blocos para poder usar em um loop catando os valores
    
    // Percorre os blocos catando nomes, quantidades e valores dos produtos com quantidade maior que zero
    for(i=1; i<=qtd_blocos ;i++)
    {
     qtdid = "qtd"+i;
     qtd   = document.getElementById(qtdid).innerHTML;
     qtd   = parseInt(qtd);
     
     if(qtd>0)
     {
      obj_tmp = {};
      
      nomeid = "nome"+i;
      nome   = document.getElementById(nomeid).innerHTML;
      
      precoid = "preco"+i;
      preco   = document.getElementById(precoid).innerHTML;
      preco   = parseFloat(preco);

      obj_tmp.nome  = nome;
      obj_tmp.preco = preco;
      obj_tmp.qtd   = qtd;
      obj_tmp.subtotal = qtd*preco;
      
      // adiciona elemento no array de dados que será enviado
      array_dados.push(obj_tmp);
     }
    }
    
    // põe o array_dados no input hidden json_dados
    document.getElementById("json_dados").value = JSON.stringify(array_dados);
    
    // envia o formulário form_pedido_produtos
    document.getElementById("form_pedido_produtos").submit();

   }
  </script>
```

Comment: Então,  vc precisa converter de string pra float pra fazer cálculo e depois de float pra string de novo pra mudar ponto pra vírgula.

Comment: Como tinha falado antes hj tô na casa da minha noiva e minha ajuda pelo cel é bem limitada,  mas tem muita gente boa nesse site pra ajudar tb.  

Comment: Alguem esta por ai ? ainda não resolvi a questão

Comment: Fala Hemerson, você deu uma olhada nessa minha resposta?
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11018/como-representar-dinheiro-em-javascript/175800#175800
Não te serve? Se quiser pode comentar nela como poderia ser melhorada.

Comment: Mano nao consegui vc lembra que agente estava conversando no skype vc me lembrou de colocar o código para aceitar os centavos desde la mano nao consegui ainda naquele codigo que vc fez tem como agente ir para o chat

Comment: Vou entrar no Skype

Comment: Liga seu Skype.