# Subtração com casas decimais no resultado

Tags: javascript, html

1. Tenho um problema que não consigo resolver, a function calcular() faz a subtração do preco pelo totalpago e mostra na quantiafalta, só que ao mostrar na quantiafalta, ele mostra assim:

Preço: 62.000
Total Pago: 60.000
Quantia em Falta: 2

E queria que ele mostrasse assim:

Preço: 62.000
Total Pago: 60.000
Quantia em Falta: 2.000

```
<script>
function calcular() {
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("Preco").value);
    var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("TotalPago").value);
    var elemResult = document.getElementById("QuantiaFalta")
    if (elemResult.textContent === undefined) {
       elemResult.textContent = String(num1 - num2);
    }
    else {
       elemResult.innerText = String(num1 - num2);
    }
}
</script>
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Pre&ccedilo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" name="fPreco" id="Preco" class="w3-input w3-animate-input" style="width:135px; border-bottom: 2px solid black" onblur="calcular();" value="<?php echo $Preco; ?>" readonly="readonly">
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Total Pago *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" name="fTotalPago" id="TotalPago" class="w3-input w3-animate-input" style="width:350px; border-bottom: 2px solid orange" onblur="calcular();" value="<?php echo $Preco; ?>" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quantia em Falta *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <span type="text" name="fQuantiaFalta" id="QuantiaFalta" class="w3-input" style="width:350px; border-bottom: 2px solid orange" required></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Quando você está criando a pergunta, você é orientado a fazer uma pesquisa aqui na comunidade para saber se este problema não foi resolvido e assim enviar conteúdos duplicados. O que você pesquisou? Convido-te também a fazer o [tour] para aprender o básico de como o site funciona.

Comment: 62.000 é 62 mil ou 62 com 3 casas decimais? O problema está ai que neste momento se for escrito 62.000 o parseInt devolve 62

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11018/como-representar-dinheiro-em-javascript)

Comment: um modo simples e setar a entrada dos inputs como 62000.00 e 60000.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução seria a adição do toFixed no final do resultado

```
function calcular() {
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("Preco").value);
    var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("TotalPago").value);
    var elemResult = document.getElementById("QuantiaFalta")
    var fixa = 3;
    if (elemResult.textContent === undefined) {
       elemResult.textContent = (num1 - num2).toFixed(fixa);
    }
    else {
       elemResult.innerText = (num1 - num2).toFixed(fixa);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O correto é verificar a quantidades de casas decimais para um retorno adequado.
Essa verificação é feita na linha  `var quantDecimais`

Com as entradas de 62.00 no input `Preço` e 60.00 no input `TotalPago` o resultado vai ser apresentado corretamente, assim como 6200.00 e 6000.00 também retornará um resultado coerente.

```js
function calcular() {

    var num1 = (document.getElementById("Preco").value);
    
    var quantDecimais = (num1 + "").split(".")[1].length;
    
    console.log (quantDecimais);       
    
    var num2 = (document.getElementById("TotalPago").value);
    var elemResult = document.getElementById("QuantiaFalta")

    if (elemResult.textContent === undefined) {
       elemResult.textContent = (num1 - num2).toFixed(quantDecimais);
    }
    else {
       elemResult.innerText = (num1 - num2).toFixed(quantDecimais);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Pre&ccedilo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" name="fPreco" id="Preco" class="w3-input w3-animate-input" style="width:135px; border-bottom: 2px solid black" onblur="calcular();" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Total Pago *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" name="fTotalPago" id="TotalPago" class="w3-input w3-animate-input" style="width:350px; border-bottom: 2px solid orange" onblur="calcular();" value="" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Quantia em Falta *</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <span type="text" name="fQuantiaFalta" id="QuantiaFalta" class="w3-input" style="width:350px; border-bottom: 2px solid orange"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o toFixed, para determinar quantas casas decimais a consulta ira retornar.
Por exemplo:

```js
function calcular() {
    var num1 = 62.000;
    var num2 = 60.000;
    var elemResult = num1-num2;
    document.write(elemResult.toFixed(3));
}
calcular();
```

Nesse caso seu valor ira retornar um valor com 3 casas decimais.

Comment: Lembrando que 62.000 para o JavaScript é sessenta e dois, enquanto tudo indica que deveria ser sessenta e dois **mil**. Ou seja, é necessário formatar o valor inicial devidamente também.

Comment: Se a entrada for 62.00 com 60.00 vai dar 2.000