# Divisão maior que R$ 999,00 resulta em NaN. Como formatar corretamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

Divisão menor que R$999,00 funciona corretamente. No entanto, maior que R$999,00 resulta em NaN. Como revolver isso? Já coloquei um replace e nada!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var demo1 = $('span.ecwid-productBrowser-price-value');
   demo1.each(function() {
   var valor1 = parseInt(this.innerHTML.replace(',', '.').substr(2) / 3, 10);
   $(this).append("<p><i>dividido por 3 é: " + valor1 + "</i></p>")
    })
  demo1.append();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>

<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$800,00</span><hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$999,00</span><hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$1.000,00</span><hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$1.200,00</span><hr>


</body>
```

Comment: Relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que começa a haver dois pontos quando o numero é na ordem de mil. Ou seja, fica assim: `parseInt(1.200.00, 10)` e isso dá bug.

Tens de remover os pontos antes de converter a virgula em ponto.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var demo1 = $('span.ecwid-productBrowser-price-value');
   demo1.each(function() {
   var valor1 = parseInt(this.innerHTML.replace(/\./g, '').replace(',', '.').substr(2) / 3, 10);
   $(this).append("<p><i>dividido por 3 é: " + valor1 + "</i></p>")
    })
  demo1.append();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>

<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$800,00</span><hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$999,00</span><hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$1.000,00</span><hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$1.200,00</span><hr>


</body>
```

Comment: Ok. Entendi. Funcionou aqui perfeitamente!

Answer (score 2):

Retire os pontos da milhar

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var demo1 = $('span.ecwid-productBrowser-price-value');
   demo1.each(function() {
   var valor1 = parseInt(this.innerHTML.replace(',', '.').substr(2) / 3, 10);
   $(this).append("<p><i>dividido por 3 é: " + valor1 + "</i></p>")
    })
  demo1.append();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>

<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$800,00</span><hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$999,00</span><hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$1000,00</span><hr>
<span class='ecwid-productBrowser-price-value'>R$1200,00</span><hr>


</body>
```

Comment: Preciso manter o ponto na milhar. Estou capturando um innerHTML variável. Mas valeu pela sugestão!

Comment: Frmz @BamDeveloper... você tb pode fazer mais um replace somente no momento do cálculo...