# Qual a forma correta de fazer cálculos

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma função de cálculos de produtos. No seguinte cenários:

- Usuário pode dar acréscimo
- Usuário pode dar desconto ( desconto sobre o valor + acréscimo )
- Usuário pode dar desconto de parceiro ( desconto sobre o valor original )

Exemplo da função:

```
function calcularValor(valorOriginal, acrescimo, desconto, descontoParceiro)
{
   var valorAcrescimo = (valorOriginal / ((100 - acrescimo) / 100)) - valorOriginal ;
   var valorDesconto = ((valorOriginal + valorAcrescimo) / 100) * desconto;
   var valorDescontoParceiro = (valorOriginal / 100) * descontoParceiro;

   return valorOriginal + valorAcrescimo  - valorDesconto  - valorDescontoParceiro;     
}
```

Porém o problema é o seguinte: Quando vou salvar o valor não está batendo em 1 centavo (não é significante para 1 pedido, mas para 1000 pedidos já está dando uma bela diferença), pois eu salvo o `valorAcrescimo`, `valorDesconto`, `valorDescontoParceiro` com 2 casas decimais.

Qual seria a forma de contornar esse problema?

Fazer o cálculo e já arredondar o valor e utilizar para fazer o outro cálculo? (Conforme o `valorAcrescimo`)

Comment: Essa pergunta não te ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/5878

Comment: Sim, ajuda bastante

Answer (score 2):

Problema aparentemente resolvido.

Utilizei a função [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11018/como-representar-dinheiro-em-javascript):

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
var n = this, 
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
   return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
 };
```

E na minha função deixei calculando com números flutuantes, mas quando salvar eu utilizei de 2 casas decimais. Caso a terceira casa depois da virgula seja maior ou igual a 5, arredonda pra cima.