# Tem como declarar uma variável em JavaScript de forma que ela sempre fique com 2 casas decimais?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

A ideia é não ter que converter o resultado para duas casas decimais sempre.
Exemplo:

```
var preco = 10.00
```

Para mostrar essas casas decimais, eu tenho que colocar assim:

```
$("#preco").html("R$ " + preco.toFixed(2));
```

e depois se eu fizer algum cálculo:

```
preco += 10
$("#preco").html("R$ " + preco.toFixed(2));
```

Novamente tenho que colocar o `toFixed(2)`.

Então a pergunta é: Existe algum modo de deixar essa variável sempre com duas casas decimais, sem ter que usar o `toFixed()` várias vezes?

Comment: Vc pode criar uma função que lhe devolva qualquer número já no formato com 2 decimais. Mas como dito na resposta do @Maniero, não tem como fazer isso desta forma que propõe a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, isso não é possível. Variáveis numéricas guardam números, não importa como é guardado.

Você pode trabalhar com a representação textual do número com as casas que deseja (note que ela usa o número como base, mas não é o número em si) como já aprendeu fazer (a única forma de garantir que não tem um erro de aproximação é transformando em `string` pra ver como é temerário usar tipos numéricos com decimais quando quer exatidão), ou pode fazer alguma conta para que o número fique aproximadamente com a quantidade de casas que deseja, pelo menos de forma significativa.

Colocar essa forma não tem nada de difícil, você deve controlar no seu código o jeito de apresentar de forma apropriada.

Aproveito para dizer que valor monetário não pode ser armazenado adequadamente o com tipo numérico padrão do JavaScript que usa ponto flutuante binário. Isto já foi respondido antes em [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101). E sim, a maioria dos sites que você vê por aí tem problemas porque não são feitos por profissionais.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como. O número sempre será salvo na precisão padrão da linguagem. Você vai ter que continuar controlando o número de casas decimais na hora de exibir.

Uma dica: Não some valores após chamar o .toFixed(2), pois este método converte o número em String. Logo, somar irá gerar uma concatenação de Strings.

```
console.log(5.5555.toFixed(2) + 10); //5.5610
```