# Arredondamento de decimal seguindo norma ABNT 5891

Tags: javascript, arredondamento

Bom dia!

**Pergunta:**

Existe alguma biblioteca, ou função, que faz arredondamentos conforme a norma ABNT NBR 5891?

**Problema:**

Tenho que implementar em JavaScript uma regra de arredondamento seguindo a norma [ABNT NBR 5891:2014](https://www.abntcatalogo.com.br/norma.aspx?ID=326535).
Tentei utilizar apenas as funções já existentes como Math.round, Math.trunc, Math.floor, Math.ceil, porem nenhuma deu 100%, a que mais chegou perto foi Math.round.

A regra e a seguinte:

1. Quando o algarismo imediatamente seguinte ao último algarismo a ser conservado for inferior a 5, o último algarismo a ser conservado permanecerá sem modificação.
2. Quando o algarismo imediatamente seguinte ao último algarismo a ser conservado for superior a 5, ou, sendo 5, for seguido de no mínimo um algarismo diferente de zero, o último algarismo a ser conservado deverá ser aumentado de uma unidade.
3. Quando o algarismo imediatamente seguinte ao último algarismo a ser conservado for 5 seguido de zeros, dever-se-á arredondar o algarismo a ser conservado para o algarismo par mais próximo. Conseqüentemente, o último algarismo a ser retirado, se for ímpar, aumentará uma unidade.
4. Quando o algarismo imediatamente seguinte ao último a ser conservado for 5 seguido de zeros, se for par o algarismo a ser conservado, ele permanecerá sem modificação.

Nos exemplos abaixo estamos aplicando a regra da ABNT arredondando para 2 casas decimais. Repare que 0 é considerado par.

EX: [0.342, 0.346, 0.3452, 0.3450, 0.332, 0.336, 0.3352, 0.3350, 0.3050, 0.3150]

Pela regra: [0.34, 0.35, 0.35, 0.34, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.3, 0.32]

Math.round [**0.34**, **0.35**, **0.35**, 0.35, **0.33**, **0.34**, **0.34**, **0.34**, 0.31, **0.32**]

Math.trunc [**0.34**, 0.34, 0.34, **0.34**, **0.33**, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, **0.3**, 0.31]

Math.floor [**0.34**, 0.34, 0.34, **0.34**, **0.33**, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, **0.3**, 0.31]

Math.ceil [0.35, **0.35**, **0.35**, 0.35, 0.34, **0.34**, **0.34**, **0.34**, 0.31, **0.32**]

Qual seria a melhor forma de adaptar essas regras no JavaScript?

Comment: Primeiramente, matematicamente falando, 0 é um número par mesmo.
Segundo, sugiro dar uma olhadinha neste link para ver a possibilidade de ter assertividade no arredondamento: https://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/JavaScript-Rounding.html

Comment: Na verdade tudo isto está errado (e quase todo mundo faz errado), o certo é isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101 arredondar em cima de um número que tem inexatidão sempre potencialmente dará resultados errados.

Comment: Não seria viável fazer um regex pra arredondar da forma que ele quer?

Comment: Olá, eu realizei esse procedimento para PHP, dê uma olhada talvez lhe auxilie. Ainda não tive tempo de refatorar, mas já atendeu aos requisitos dos testes.

https://github.com/fhferreira/round