# Meu código não calcula dígitos após a vírgula

Tags: javascript, html

Consegui ajuda aqui no site pra conseguir fazer minhas variáveis me retornarem apenas 2 números após a vírgula, porem o código nunca calcula número colocados com vírgula, como 140,45 por exemplo.
Meu código só calcula número inteiros no prompt.
O que posso fazer pra arrumar isso?

```html
    var valorDoAbastecimento = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor do abastecimento")) ;

    var totalDeLitrosAbastecido = valorDoAbastecimento / 3.09

    var descontoPorLitro = 0.10 ;

    var totalDesconto = totalDeLitrosAbastecido * descontoPorLitro ;

    var dinheiroPago = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor pago em dinheiro."));

    var valorTotalComDesconto = valorDoAbastecimento - totalDesconto

    var troco = dinheiroPago - valorTotalComDesconto;



    mostra ("<b>O total de litros abastecido é de: </b><mark><ins>" + totalDeLitrosAbastecido.toFixed(2) + " Litros") ;
    mostra ("</mark><b></ins>O valor do desconto nesta compra é de </b><mark><ins>" + totalDesconto.toFixed(2) + " R$");
    mostra ("<b></mark></ins>O Valor total da compra com o desconto fica:</b> " + "<mark><ins>" + valorTotalComDesconto.toFixed(2) + " R$")
    mostra ("</mark></ins><b>O troco do cliente é de </b><mark><ins>" + troco.toFixed(2) + " R$");

</script>
```

Comment: Não utilizar vírgula. O separador decimal no JS é o ponto, então ao invés de colocar `140,45` coloque `140.45`, ou faça o tratamento para substituir esse caractere.

Comment: E leia também [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/5878)