# Tipos de dados SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tipagem

Estou com uma dúvida a respeito do tipo de dados `real` no SQL Server.

Estou tentando armazenar o valor de 1.5 em um tipo real  porem ele representa **1.5** como **1,5**, queria saber se quando eu for passar esse valor para uma variável em JavaScript teria algum problema por conta da "," em vez de "."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está confundindo representação textual do número com o número em si. Se vai guardar o número 1.5, ele não tem ponto ou vírgula, ele tem uma unidade inteira e metade de uma unidade na parte decimal. O ponto ou vírgula faz parte da representação textual, isto depende de como for usar para apresentar no SQL Server, mas se pegar o número ele é só um número, ele tem uma parte inteira e uma decimal controlada de forma própria.

Qualquer linguagem que pegue o número terá o número de forma correta, e é função do programador escolher a forma de apresentar quando isso for necessário, no meio do processo para fazer cálculos não tem que se preocupar com o caractere usado para separação da parte decimal porque isto não existe.

Porém tem grande chance de estar usando um valor monetário aí, e tem um erro em dois lugares, um no SQL Server e outro no JavaScript (quase todo mundo comete esse erro e causa problemas que nem sempre são aparentes). Veja mais em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101) e [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101).