# Estou criando um conversor de moeda, e ele retorna um valor errado

Tags: javascript

A partir do mult3 ele retorna um valor errado, no mult3 por exemplo ele tem que retornar 0.83 quando o valor enviado é 1, mas retorna 0.15 oque é errado.

```js
  let money_cov = {
      get_in(){
          let select = document.getElementById('moeda_in');
          let value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
          return value;
      },
      get_out(){
          let select = document.getElementById('moeda_out');
          let value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
          return value;
      },
      mul(){
          switch (this.get_in(),this.get_out()) {
           case 'real', 'dolar':
              let mult_real_dolar = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor_entrada").value)) * 0.18;
              alert(mult_real_dolar.toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}));
           break;
           case 'real', 'euro':
              let mult_real_euro = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor_entrada").value)) * 0.15;
              alert(mult_real_euro.toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}));    
           break;
           case 'dolar', 'real':
              let mult_dolar_real = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor_entrada").value)) * 5.59;
              alert(mult_dolar_real.toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}));    
           break;
           case 'dolar', 'euro':
              let mult_dolar_euro = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor_entrada').value)) * 0.83;
              alert(mult_dolar_euro.toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}));
           break;
           case 'euro', 'real':
              let mult_euro_real = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor_entrada').value)) * 6.73;  
              alert(mult_euro_real.toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'}));   
           break;
           case 'euro', 'dolar':     
              let mult_euro_dolar = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor_entrada').value)) * 1.20;   
              alert(mult_euro_dolar.toLocaleString('pt-br', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'})); 
           break;
           default:
               alert('Erro!');
          }
      },
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="moeda_in">Moeda de entrada:</label>
  <select name="valor_in" id="moeda_in">
    <option value="real" selected>Real Brasileiro</option>
    <option value="dolar">Dolar Americano</option>
    <option value="euro">Euro</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <label for="moeda_out">Moeda de saida:</label>
  <select name="valor_out" id="moeda_out">
    <option value="real">Real Brasileiro</option>
    <option value="dolar" selected>Dolar Americano</option>
    <option value="euro">Euro</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- Entrada de Valores a Serem Convertidos || Botao para mostrar Resultado -->
<div>
  <input type="number"  id="valor_entrada" value="1">
  <button type="submit" onclick="money_cov.mul()">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: o que quer dizer com "não consigo"? algum erro?

Comment: a partir do mult3 ele retorna um valor errado, no mult3 por exemplo ele tem que retornar 0.83 quando o valor enviado é 1, mas retorna 0.15 oque é errado. Entendeu?

Answer (score 1):

> ## *Atenção:*
>
> ### Valores monetários não devem ser modelados como números de pontos flutuante, devido a imprecisão intrínseca ao numerais descritos na norma [IEEE 754](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4610935).
>
> #### O escopo dessa resposta se restringe a codificação da solução lógica do exercício.
>
> #### Para mais detalhes veja:
>
> #### [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11018/como-representar-dinheiro-em-javascript)

É um código muito verboso para um problema simples.

Em seu objeto literal `money_cov` as funções `get_in()` e `get_out()` estão realizando processamento desnecessário, já que o elemento *HTML* [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) possui o atributo `value` que reflete o valor do elemento *HTML*  selecionado.
Facilmente essa funções podem ser trocadas por uma propriedade associada a um [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Quanto a função `mul()` é criado uma complexa estrutura de verificação onde uma simples divisão resolve o problema:

Criando uma tabela onde se fixa o real como unidade e as demais moeda como múltiplos desse real.

| Moeda | Coeficiente(R$) |
| --- | --- |
| real | 1.00 |
| dólar | 5.59 |
| euro | 6.73 |

<sup><sup>Tabela de conversão</sup></sup>.

O resultado da conversão é igual a quantidade a ser convertida vezes o coeficiente da moeda de entrada dividido pelo coeficiente da moeda de saída:

```
    Valorconvertido = (Valorentrada * Coeficienteentrada) / Coeficientesaída
```

Para facilitar a formatação da saída também foi criada uma tabela de localizações monetárias:

| Moeda | Código ISO 4217 |
| --- | --- |
| real | BRL |
| dólar | USD |
| euro | EUR |

<sup><sup>Tabela parcial ISO 4217</sup></sup>.

```js
const tabela_coef = {
  real: 1.00,
  dolar: 5.59,
  euro: 6.73
}

const tabela_loc = {
  real: "BRL",
  dolar: "USD",
  euro: "EUR"
}

const money_cov = {
  get in() {
    return document.getElementById('moeda_in').value;
  },
  get out() {
    return document.getElementById('moeda_out').value;
  },
  mul() {
    let entrada = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor_entrada').value);
    let converção = entrada * tabela_coef[this.in] / tabela_coef[this.out];
    alert(converção.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: tabela_loc[this.out]
    }));
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="moeda_in">Moeda de entrada:</label>
  <select name="valor_in" id="moeda_in">
    <option value="real" selected>Real Brasileiro</option>
    <option value="dolar">Dolar Americano</option>
    <option value="euro">Euro</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <label for="moeda_out">Moeda de saida:</label>
  <select name="valor_out" id="moeda_out">
    <option value="real">Real Brasileiro</option>
    <option value="dolar" selected>Dolar Americano</option>
    <option value="euro">Euro</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- Entrada de Valores a Serem Convertidos || Botao para mostrar Resultado -->
<div>
  <input type="number" id="valor_entrada" value="1">
  <button type="button" onclick="money_cov.mul()">Send</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O `switch` em JavaScript não permite múltiplos parâmetros da forma que você codificou, separando os valores no `case` com virgula. Troque a lógica para `if/else` para poder comparar o valor de 2 variáveis ou utilize um objeto do tipo chave valor como fiz abaixo na refatoração do seu código.

```js
let money_cov = {
  get_in() {
    let select = document.getElementById('moeda_in');
    let value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    return value;
  },
  get_out() {
    let select = document.getElementById('moeda_out');
    let value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    return value;
  },
  mul() {
    const possibilidades = {
      'real->dolar': {
        fator: 0.18,
        currency: 'BRL'
      },
      'real->euro': {
        fator: 0.15,
        currency: 'BRL'
      },
      'dolar->real': {
        fator: 5.59,
        currency: 'USD'
      },
      'dolar->euro': {
        fator: 0.83,
        currency: 'USD'
      },
      'euro->real': {
        fator: 6.73,
        currency: 'EUR'
      },
      'euro->dolar': {
        fator: 1.20,
        currency: 'EUR'
      },
    };

    const opcaoSelecionada = `${this.get_in()}->${this.get_out()}`;
    console.log(opcaoSelecionada);
    const parametros = possibilidades[opcaoSelecionada];

    if (!parametros) {
      alert('Não implementado');
      return;
    }

    const valorEntrada = (parseFloat(document.getElementById("valor_entrada").value));
    const valorSaida = valorEntrada * parametros.fator;
    console.log(valorSaida);

    alert(valorSaida.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: parametros.currency
    }));
  },
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="moeda_in">Moeda de entrada:</label>
    <select name="valor_in" id="moeda_in">
         <option value="real" selected>Real Brasileiro</option>
         <option value="dolar">Dolar Americano</option>
         <option value="euro">Euro</option>
    </select>        

    <br>

    <label for="moeda_out">Moeda de saida:</label>
    <select name="valor_out" id="moeda_out">
         <option value="real">Real Brasileiro</option>
         <option value="dolar" selected>Dolar Americano</option>
         <option value="euro">Euro</option>
    </select>   
</div>

<!-- Entrada de Valores a Serem Convertidos || Botao para mostrar Resultado -->

<div>
    <input type="number"  id="valor_entrada" value="1">
    <button type="submit" onclick="money_cov.mul()">Send</button>
</div>
```