# Soma de Float. Solução alternativa para o erro do 0.30000000000000004 do Java Script

Tags: javascript, float

Estou fazendo uma lista de exercícios sobre Java Script e a questão onde pede

> **05) Lidar com números em JavaScript pode dar muita dor de cabeça.
>
> Você já viu o que acontece quando faz o seguinte comando no console: `console.log(0.1 + 0.2);` O resultado será: `0.30000000000000004`.
>
> Outra coisa importante de observar, é o fato que o ponto é utilizado no lugar da vírgula e vice versa.
>
> Com isso, vamos fazer um exercício simples para mostrar dinheiro sempre da forma correta. Desenvolva uma função JavaScript para que ela receba um valor como 0`.30000000000000004 e` retorne `R$0,30` (observe a vírgula e o ponto).**"

eu consegui uma solução intuitiva que resolvia que foi:

```
function reais(valorQuebrado){
        return `R$:${Math.floor(valorQuebrado)},${Math.floor(100 * valorQuebrado)}`
}

console.log(reais(0.30000000000000004))
console.log(reais(0.2 + 0.1))
```

Entretanto, a solução do exercícios me deu outro tipo de solução que foi:

```
function formatarValorDecimal(valorDecimal) {
    valorEmReais = `R$ ${valorDecimal.toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",")}`
    console.log(valorEmReais)
}

formatarValorDecimal(0.1 + 0.2)
```

Gostaria de saber se há diferença entre as respostas, ou se a minha resposta não atinge os casos gerais, assim podendo ser um futuro erro de código.

Comment: Tem casos que dá diferença sim, por causa do  arredondamento (e a primeira não garante somente duas casas decimais), veja: https://ideone.com/SXz4LT <-- aqui também tem outra alternativa, com `toLocaleString`. Também é interessante ler: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/112052